# Visual BPMN 2.0 diff tool for JBPM

Tags: algorithm, xml-parsing, jbpm, bpmn

I would like to know what would be in your opinion the easiest/more efficient way to create a visual tool to compare BPMN 2.0 processes using JBPM web designer?

Comment: From the 2 `XML`s (old, new) create new "diff" `XML` using some existing text-oriented diff algorithm where the "added" things would be marked as green "removed" marked as red and "modified" marked as blue? If the "diff" `XML` will be properly formatted `BPMN` file then you can show the differences visually. Adding some of the `algorithm` tags to your question may attract some helpful clever witty guys. Right now your challenging question is rather too broad and opinion-based and not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks for the answer xmojmr, I will add the suggested tags. What do you think about the x-diff algorithm for change detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...way to create a visual tool to compare `BPMN 2.0` processes using `JBPM` web designer?

I don't know how I'd implement it, neither what can `JBPM` designer do neither if it's already solved in an existing tool so I can't pick some *easiest* or *efficient* solution.

But based on the fact that `BPMN` models are actually `XML` files and `XML` files are actually `text` files, I would **try** to reduce the problem to the **text diff** visualization.

From the 2 `XML`s (old, new) create new "diff" `XML` using some existing text-oriented diff algorithm where the "added" things would be marked as **green** "removed" marked as **red** and "modified" marked as **blue**. If the resulting "diff" `XML` would be properly formatted `BPMN` file then just showing it in a `BPMN` viewer would show the differences visually.

I don't keep track of the text diff or binary diff problem for quite long time, but besides consulting [Wikipedia: DIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIFF) topic, some proven sources I'm aware of are:

1. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/) is very mature and useful text-diff tool and it's source code repository contains some text-diff algorithms implemented in `C++` and `C` - [sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Src/diffutils/src](http://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Src/diffutils/src/)
2. Angus Johnson created awesome freeware with source code [TextDiff tool](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html) implemented in `Delphi`. The application is build around `TDiff` component which is (according to the readme) based on papers "An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations" by E Myers - Algorithmica Vol. 1 No. 2, 1986, pp. 251-266 and "An O(NP) Sequence Comparison Algorithm" by Sun Wu, Udi Manber & Gene Myers. Both papers in `PDF` and their source code incarnation are included in the downloadable `zip`
3. As side product of computing [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings can be set of "add", "copy", "delete" operations needed to transform the old string to the new one. If you assign colors to the operations you can get the colored visualization of the difference

All of the above contains some "Computer Science" stuff, which was for me difficult to comprehend, but the corresponding code simply does work. For instance while studying the Angus Johnson's tool (I was adding support for comparing complete folders not only files) there were some notes in the comments and readmes claiming that

→ comparing text files is special case of comparing vectors of strings which is special case of comparing vectors of numbers (string hashes) which is some *straighforward(?)* N-dimensional math problem(!?)

I'm selling what I've bought few years ago, understanding it and using it is up to you, but I believe it might be useful ;)